# Change the right panel background when a record is found

Tags: c#

I could use a little bit of help on the following matter:

I have 31 panels for each day in the month.
I want to change the background of a panel whenever there is a record found (in the dataset) on that day.

If you take a look at the code you can see where i'm going, all panels need to be pointed out separately. This looks to long if you ask me. I think you need to make a index for all panels?

Is there another/better way of doing this? And if so, how?

```
        int MaxRows;
        MaxRows = ds.Tables["Dataset"].Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i != (MaxRows); i++)
        {
            DataRow dRow = ds.Tables["Dataset"].Rows[i];

            if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "1")
            {
                panDay1.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "2")
            {
                panDay2.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "3")
            {
                panDay3.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "4")
            {
                panDay4.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "5")
            {
                panDay5.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "6")
            {
                panDay6.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "7")
            {
                panDay7.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "8")
            {
                panDay8.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "9")
            {
                panDay9.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "10")
            {
                panDay10.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "11")
            {
                panDay11.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "12")
            {
                panDay12.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "13")
            {
                panDay13.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            else if (dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() == "14")
            {
                panDay14.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            }
            etc. 
            etc.
            etc.
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index the controls collection with a string.  Which permits this syntax:

```
    for (int i = 0; i != (MaxRows); i++)
    {
        DataRow dRow = ds.Tables["Dataset"].Rows[i];
        this.Controls["panDay" + dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1)].BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
    }
```

Comment: This one suites me the best. Thank's everybody for the quick help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an array of all 31 panels.

You can then write

```
panelArray[(int)dRow.ItemArray[i]].BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create panels dynamically and adds panels to the one parent panel. Give each panel with unique ID for eg. panelDay_1,panelDay_2, panelDay_31. Now access the corresponding panel using

```
//Create panels dynamically
for(int i=0;i<dataTable.Rows.Count.i++)
{
     Panel p=new Panel();
     p.Name="panelDay_" + i;

     //Write code to set panels location and size

     //Add panel to the panels parent
     parentPanel.Controls.Add(p);
}

//Now access panel with the name
parentPanel.Controls["panelDay_" + i].Color=Color.Blue;
```

Comment: Nice idea, although it doesn't require him to change design so the panels are created on the fly - since he already named them panDay1, panDay2, ...

Answer (score 0):

Oh! actually I think we can access with out creating the array also. If we observe he has given panel names in sequntial way. like this

```
panDay1
panDay2
panDay3
  .
  .
panDay31.
```

If that is case and if we assume that Control c is parent of alll the panels then we can access it using the name like this

```
 //Assuming form itself is the parent then
 c=this;
 c.Cotrols["panDay" + i].BackColor=Color.Blue;
```

Hope it helps.